# ViewModel returned by View (PartialView) is empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

Please help me to understand why my view model is returned by view as empty. I tried to find solution in google, but vast majority  of advices is to add hidden. But for me adding Html.HiddenFor didn't work
Here is my code

**ViewModels**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public FilterViewModel Filter {get; set;}

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Filter = new FilterViewModel();
    }
}

public class FilterViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TimeUnits { get; set; }
    public string SelectedTimeUnit { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();
        model.Filter.TimeUnits = new SelectList( new string[] {"week", "month", "year"});

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        *here I have empty model*
        return View();
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model Mvc4WebApplication.Models.MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Filter.SelectedTimeUnit)
    @Html.Partial("_FilterPartial", Model.Filter)

    <input type="submit" class="ok" value="OK" />
}
```

**PartialView**

```
@model Mvc4WebApplication.Models.FilterViewModel

<div class="select">
    <div class="background">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedTimeUnit, Model.TimeUnits as SelectList, "Select time unit", new { onchange = "FetchPeriods();" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanx in advance.

**UPD**
Generated HTML looks like that

```
<form action="/" method="post">
   <input id="Filter_SelectedTimeUnit" name="Filter.SelectedTimeUnit" type="hidden" value="">
   <div class="select">
       <div class="background">
           <select id="SelectedTimeUnit" name="SelectedTimeUnit" onchange="FetchPeriods();">
               <option value="">Select time unit</option>
               <option>week</option>
               <option>month</option>
               <option>year</option>
           </select>
       </div>
</div>
    <input type="submit" class="ok" value="OK">
</form>
```

Comment: What's the generated HTMl look like? Also, why are you using a partial `_FilterPartial` over an `EditorTemplate`?

Comment: I've added generated html to my question above. I've put here simplified example. I use this partial view in several places in my system

Comment: Why is `SelectedTimeUnit` referenced twice; Once as a hidden input, a second time in the partial view? I also never see `TimeUnits` displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still looking for an answer after 4 years, but I just ran into the same thing and found this solution:

Change your

```
@Html.Partial("_FilterPartial", Model.Filter)
```

to

```
@Html.Partial("_FilterPartial", Model.Filter,
       new ViewDataDictionary(Html.ViewData)
       {
            TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = Html.NameFor(m => m.Filter).ToString() }
       })
```

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36848815/how-to-update-view-model-in-a-partial-view-in-mvc5)